# image texture doesn't work

Tags: texturing, image

I made a manatee object and took a picture of the toy's fabric. 
I try to add the jpg file as image texture but it seems doesn't work.

could anyone help me with this problem?? (T-T)
Thank you very much.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The manatee model has no UV map. So Blender does not know how to use the texture image.

You can either create a UV map, or change the vector input of the image texture node.

Below, add a *'texture coordinates'* node and plug *object* or *generated* output to the image texture node.

Then change projection method to *'box'*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much !! sorry I haven't figure out uv texture before, but your answer is very helpful to me. (now I'm thinking about how to adjust the fluff size of the fabric texture, because the single fluff of the manatee looks a little huge. Should I just adjust it in uv map or add a new node to fix it?(THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP)

Comment: It depends of what you want to do after. With UV map you can change the scale but in that case, UV map will lead to seams. Another is to add a vector mapping node between 'texture coordinates' and the image and change the scale.

Comment: I tried the "mapping" node, it really works but some fluff were stretched，maybe I still need to change the scale in UV map(I marked the seams in early time), Thank you very much for your help